# How to change the @Transactional transactionManager used by profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have two `TransactionManagers` within an application.
I run the app with `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev/test/prod`.

```
@Service
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional("txName")
public class MyService {

}
```

Now, depending on the profile I want to change the transaction manager name. So that automatically in dev profile the `txDev` is used, whereas prod would use `txProd` as name.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Use only one transaction manager and set it in the profile

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyService {}
```

In xml (same logic with java config)

```
<beans profile="prod">
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
</beans>

<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Comment: I have to use two tx managers (for accessing two different databases at the same time). But depending on the profile, I want to use on or the other tx manager for specific transations.

Comment: For the same service ?

Comment: yes from the same service. That's why I wrote I'd like to switch the txName of the `@Transactional` annotation by active profile.

Comment: No sure to understand ! if the 2 transactions managers will be used at the same time the spring profile is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @benbenw what alternatives are there then to achieve what membersound is looking for?